# How to query all items between specific values? (MongoDB, NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, momentjs

I have the database collection as such:

```
{
    data: [
        item: {
            date: "2022-03-22T08:10:37.023Z"
        },
        item: {
            date: "2022-03-22T08:11:04.023Z"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I also have variables `start_date` and `end_date` which are `momentjs` dates. I can compare dates with `isAfter()` and `isBefore()` methods.

How to get all items with date between `start_date` and `end_date`?

Note: `date: "..."` is a `string` and not `ISODate` object.

`data` is an array.

I can also convert the date `string` to `momentjs` date for comparison.

Comment: You may not get many answers to this, because you haven't shown what code you wrote to try to build the query yourself.  You'll get the best answers when you provide the example data (as you have) and also an example or sample query you wrote to attempt a solution yourself.

Comment: Use an aggregation pipeline with [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/). If you want more help you have to provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

1. looks like your `date` is in ISO format so the moment constructor should accept it, e.g.

```js
moment(date);
```

To prove it, convert it into a plain js `Date` object and print it

```js
moment("2022-03-22T08:11:04.023Z").toDate()
// Tue Mar 22 2022 10:11:04 GMT+0200 (Israel Standard Time)
```

2. You may want to look at [isBetween](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/)

```js
moment(date).isBetween(start_date, end_date);
```

Will return true if `date` is between those two moments.

3. After that you can use something like [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove the data items that are not between your range and that's about it.